# Query using two column values to create range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a start time timestamp column and a length integer column representing minutes. I want to be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table t 
    WHERE t.start_time + interval 't.length minutes' < '2011-10-21';
```

But this doesn't work. Is there any way to get a new timestamp from the two column values?

I'm running version 8.3 of postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   table 
WHERE  (start_time + interval '1 min' * length_minutes) < '2011-10-21 0:0'::timestamp;
```

#### Notes

- Simply multiply your `integer` with 1-minute intervals and add it to the `timestamp`.
- It is slightly faster to compare the `timestamp` to a `timestamp`. A `date` would have to be cast to `timestamp` (automatically).

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast `t.length` as a `character` and then append it... try this instead?

```
SELECT * 
FROM table t 
WHERE 
    t.start_time 
    + cast(cast(t.length as character varying) || ' minutes' as interval) 
    < '2011-10-21';
```