# How do I add a column to a date in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, date, math, intervals

I’m using Postgres 9. I’m trying to do date math with a column in my table that is an integer. I’m trying this:

```
select current_timestamp + interval age || ' years'
from my_table
where age is not null
limit 5;
```

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "||"
> LINE 1: select current_timestamp + interval age || ' years' from rac...
> ```

What is the proper way to write this? I’m trying to add the `age` column, which is in years, to the current timestamp (now)?

Comment: Ain't no such thing as "PostGresql 9". I fixed the name, the version is still undefined. Consider [naming](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines) and [versioning guidelines](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning) of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply your `integer` with 1-year intervals and add it to the timestamp:

```
SELECT current_timestamp + interval '1 year' * age
FROM   my_table
WHERE  age IS NOT NULL
LIMIT  5;
```

Related:

- [Query using two column values to create range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856067/query-using-two-column-values-to-create-range/7856327#7856327)