# Cast integer with hour to time in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, time, syntax, casting

I have a number passed as `integer` and would like to convert it to `time`, and use this number as hour.

I have found solutions for using a number as minutes, but I'm not familiar with PostgreSQL syntax. Not sure what to do here:

```
select CAST(to_char(czas, 'FM99909:99') AS TIME WITHOUT   
TIME ZONE)::TIME from test
```

The result would be:

```
00:15:00
```

But I'm looking for a way to make it:

```
15:00:00
```

I have been working with MS SQL for quite a while, I'm surprised how much more complex PostgreSQL syntax is.

Comment: New terrain always seems more complex at first. Wait till you have gathered some experience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your column `test.czas` to signifies *hours* just multiply with `interval '1 hour'`:

```
SELECT (interval '01:00' * czas)::time FROM test;
```

Produces your desired result exactly, even with fractional digits.

`'01:00'` and `'1 hour'` are equivalent [`interval` literals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#datatype-interval-input).
For `czas` > 24 you get the remainder (full days cut off) - like if you'd use `czas%24`.

Related:

- [Postgres data type cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676816/postgres-data-type-cast/13676871#13676871)
- [How do I add a column to a date in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38154217/how-do-i-add-a-column-to-a-date-in-postgres/38154229#38154229)